# Estimating the Twin prime constant

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

On this website:

http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Primes/twin.html

it says:
"*This last constant occurs in some asymptotic estimations involving primes and it's interesting to observe that it may be estimated using properties of the Riemann Zeta function to thousand of digits (Sebah computed it to more than 5000 digits).*"

Can someone explain how you can use the Riemann zeta function to estimate the digits of the twin prime constant?

Comment: Did you try the reference? T. Nicely, Enumeration to $10^{14}$ of the Twin Primes and Brun's Constant, Virginia J. Sci., (1996), vol. 46, p. 195-204

Comment: Perhaps even better: http://www.trnicely.net/twins/twins2.html

Answer (score 1):

There exists a formula that gives a series with accelerated convergence for the twin prime constant, due to Flajolet and Vardi (1996). If we denote the twin prime constant by $\Pi_2$, we have:

$$
\Pi_2 = \prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left[\zeta(n)(1-2^{-n})\right]^{-I_n},
$$

where

$$
 I_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)2^{n/d}.
$$

The values of $I_n$ can be found in the OEIS as sequence **A001037**:
$$
I_n = 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18, 30, 56, 99, \ldots
$$